# DJANGO: blank select option missing in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, widget, modelform

I have the following:

MODEL.PY

```
LIST = (('Manager', 'Manager'),('Non-Manager', 'Non-Manager'),)

class Employee(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=LIST, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fname

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fname = forms.CharField(required=True, label='First Name')
    manager = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=Select(choices=LIST), label='Their Position?')
    comment = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 10}), label='Comments')
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

If I remove manager from the EmployeeForm, I get a "------" as an option in the forms drop down menu, but if I keep manager in the EmployeeForm (and I need to in order to override the fields label), it removes the "------". How do I allow the EmployeeForm to keep the "------" option?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, please see corrected question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like:

```
manager = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=Select(choices=(('', '----------'),) + LIST), label='Their Position?')
```

Comment: So I've seen this solution. I guess I'll try it but I guess I'm wondering why is it that if I remove Manager from EmployeeForm, it gives me that option by default? and sets it as the default option?

Comment: When it does it automatically, it knows that `blank=True`, so therefore adds the blank option. If you're doing it on your own, with your own widget then it is up to you to create the correct choices.

Comment: is there no way to put blank=True in the widget?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a MultipleSelect where there is no "---------" option..

Comment: Although, why are you using a Select widget for a CharField?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9794/discussion-between-dgel-and-odpogn)

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to django.. is there a better option than CharField?

Comment: Discussed in chat, you can use verbose_name in the model! simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).